# Ribet's proof of open image for elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, galois-representations

In [Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-22/issue-1/Review--Jean-Pierre-Serre-Abelian-l-adic-representations-and/bams/1183555477.full), Ribet gives a proof of Serre's open image theorem for elliptic curves using results from Faltings' proof of the Mordell conjecture. His argument is also repeated at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108169/modern-proof-of-serres-open-image-theorem.

Unfortunately, I don't understand how he uses Faltings' Theorem to arrive at the punchline.

1. What does it mean for $\rho_{\ell, E}$ to be semisimple? I thought a semisimple representation was a direct sum of irreducibles, but Shafarevich's Theorem already guarantees that $V_{\ell}$ is irreducible.
2. What is the significant of the fact that $\text{End}_{\mathfrak{g}_{\ell}}(V_{\ell}) \simeq \mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$  (in the case of a non-CM elliptic curve)?

To summarize, how do these two results rule out the case of a non-split Cartan?

Comment: If you get no answer here, you might find that [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) is a better place for your question.

Comment: @TonyK The question was edited recently, but was originally asked nearly a decade ago haha.